# @IBDesignable build failed

Tags: xcode, swift, ibdesignable

I have a weird problem with Xcode. I want to use `@IBDesignable` so I have this code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var inset: CGFloat = 0

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 25.0 {
        didSet {
            setupView()
        }
    }

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds, inset, inset)
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return textRectForBounds(bounds)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }

}
```

and this file is called `CustomTextField.swift`

On my storyboard I have text field and when I input custom class I get: 
[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]

Another interesting thing is when I change background... It is changed if I restart Xcode. Not before. Like it is frozen.

I tried to delete derivative data, clean, build dozen times. Nothing helps. I even created new project with just one text field and this custom class and I get the same error.

When I add this pod then it says Designables build failed.

UPDATE :
I recorded my screen. http://d.pr/v/10bOl/17myjDu4
It seems I didn't mess my code but it is something else.

UPDATE 2:
I did sudo gem install cocoapods --pre and that managed to solve build failed. Now it is up to date. But I still get some errors.

[image]

Comment: Is the class of your view in Interface Builder set to `CustomTextField`?

Comment: Yes, it is set to CustomTextField

Comment: @KiraArik That does not seem to be the case because your error message says the instance is of class `UITextField`. Please look again. Maybe there is a second text field somewhere?